# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"right" | "inherit" | "left" | "center" | "justify" | undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The same problem is asked in this question but It didn't answer my question as to why we need to use 'as' to make it work:
[TS2322 Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"left" | "center" | "right" | undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519460/ts2322-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-left-center-right-un)

I have the following code but it's showing error

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"right" | "inherit" | "left" | "center" | "justify" | undefined'`

even though the value is in one of the values allowed.

```js
interface DataTableHeader {
  key: string
  label: string
  align?: "right" | "inherit" | "left" | "center" | "justify"
}

const columns = [
    {
        key: "title",
        label: "Title",
    },
    {
        align: "right",
        key: "costPrice",
        label: "Cost Price", 
    }
]

const DataTable = (columns?: DataTableHeader[]) => {
    return columns
}

DataTable(columns) // here

// Errors in code
Argument of type '({ key: string; label: string; align?: undefined; } | { align: string; key: string; label: string; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataTableHeader[]'.
  Type '{ key: string; label: string; align?: undefined; } | { align: string; key: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DataTableHeader'.
    Type '{ align: string; key: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DataTableHeader'.
      Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"right" | "inherit" | "left" | "center" | "justify" | undefined'.
```

[image]

Comment: If you explicitly type `columns` it won't error. `const columns:DataTableHeader[] = [...` (and will give you typechecking on the objects in `columns` as well) [tsPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/NDDDRN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type `const columns` as `DataTableHeader[]`, otherwise it implicitly gets the type `({ key: string; label: string; align?: undefined; } | { align: string; key: string; label: string; })[]`.

```js
const columns: DataTableHeader[] = [ ... ]
```

Note that you will also get errors if you try to add in invalid object in this assignment due to that type:

```js
const columns: DataTableHeader[] = [
    {
        // Type '"wrong"' is not assignable to type '"right" | "inherit" | "left" | "center" | "justify" | undefined'.
        //      |
        //      v
        align: "wrong",
        key: "costPrice",
        label: "Cost Price", 
    }
]
```